# Start a process with DialogResult c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dialogresult

I am actually writing a program that creates specific excel files I need, with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. This works fine.

My program creates, then safes and close the new excel file (works fine).

```
 sheet.SaveCopyAs(path);
 sheet.Saved = true;
 sheet.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
 excel.Quit();
```

When the new Excel File was created successfully a DialogResult Box opens and asks if I want to open the new Excel file or not

```
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Open new file?", "text", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
          {
             if (DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
             {
                  Process.Start(path);
             }
             else if (DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
             {                          
                   this.Close();
             }
```

But when I press YES, nothing happens, the new file does not open.

I tried it with an extra button on my form

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(path);
        }
```

This way works, but why is the DialogResult Box not opening my new Excel File?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your dialog Result value is stored in `dr`, so you should compare the `dr`:

```
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Open new file?", "text",  
                                  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Process.Start(path);
}
else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
{                          
     this.Close();
}
```